# jQuery Connect four - help debugging function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having problems with my jQuery homework (I'm a student and a JS beginner).

Basically the assignment is to create a Connect four game with jQuery using the MV(C) (we don't use the controller) schema.

The playing field is a 2D array and looks like this.

```
- , - , - , - , - , - , - 
- , - , - , - , - , - , - 
- , - , - , - , - , - , - 
- , - , - , - , - , - , - 
- , - , - , - , - , - , - 
- , - , - , - , - , - , -
```

and the players play by pressing the columns (f.ex. Player 1 presses 3)

```
- , - , - , - , - , - , - 
- , - , - , - , - , - , - 
- , - , - , - , - , - , - 
- , - , - , - , - , - , - 
- , - , - , - , - , - , - 
- , - , x , - , - , - , -
```

and the Player 2 presses 4

```
- , - , - , - , - , - , - 
- , - , - , - , - , - , - 
- , - , - , - , - , - , - 
- , - , - , - , - , - , - 
- , - , - , - , - , - , - 
- , - , x , o , - , - , -
```

and so on.

When the game is over the winning four letter should change to uppercase.

I'm stuck and don't really know how to go on so I created a GitHub repository with all the code.

https://github.com/VeronicaLeeds/connectfour

Basically it initializes the playing field and you can press the numbers but then the play() method won't work.

It would be great if anyone could tell me why it doesn't change the value of the array from - to x/o ?

This is the code:

```
checkAvailableRow(column) {
            for (var i = 5 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
                console.log(currentPlayer);
                if (playFieldArray[column][i] === "-") {
                    return i;
                    if(currentPlayer == "Player 1"){
                        playFieldArray[column][i] = "x";
                    } else {
                        playFieldArray[column][i] = "o";
                    }

                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
```

And why the checkIfWon() function in the Model.js isn't working.

Would be eternally grateful for any help.

Comment: Well, one small detail, usually in a 2 dimensional array the first bracket is the row, not the column.

Answer (score 0):

```
return i;
```

A return causes the logical process to return out of the function it is in.  As such, none of the logic after it will ever happen.  Comment this statement and see if anything changes for you (it should).

Or move it to after the if/else that changes the array value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to get available index of the y axes when providing a grid and x value:

```js
//function to get available index for y when given grid and x
//  it will return false if no y is available
const getY = (grid,index)=>{
  const getIndex = (arr,index) => {
    if(arr[index]==="-"){
      return index;
    }
    if(index<0){
      return false;
    }
    return getIndex(arr,index-1);
  }
  return getIndex(grid[index],grid[index].length-1);
}

//Run some tests:
const rotate = grid =>//just to make the grid look normal in console.log
  grid[0].map((i,y)=>grid.map((i,x)=>[y,x]))
  .map((row)=>row.map(([y,x])=>grid[x][y]));
const format = grid => rotate(grid).map(row=>row.join(" ")).join("\n");

//function to mutate grid setting items for testing
const setItem = (x,grid,value) => y => grid[x][y]=value;
//7 by 6 grid containing -
const grid = Array.from(new Array(7),()=>Array.from(new Array(6),()=>"-"));
//add some values to grid
[0,1,2,3,4,5].forEach(x=>[0,1,2,3,4,5].slice(x).forEach(setItem(x,grid,"O")));
console.log("grid is:");
console.log(format(grid));
//see the values for y when asking for 
console.log("Testing....");
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6].forEach(
  x=>console.log(`y is ${getY(grid,x)} when x is:${x}`)
);
```

The following is a function to check if a player wins given a grid and a position.

```js
const isWin = (grid,position) => {
  const [x,y] = position;
  const player = grid[x][y];
  if(player==="-"){//current location in grid is empty, return false
    return false;
  }
  const countConnectedAllDirections = (directions,position,player) => {
    const connectCount = (direction,position,player,count=1)=>{
      const [x,y]=[position[0]+count*direction[0],position[1]+count*direction[1]];
      if((grid[x] && grid[x][y])!==player){
        return count;
      }
      return connectCount(direction,position,player,count+1);
    };
    return directions.map(
      ([back,forward])=>[connectCount(back,position,player),forward]
    ).map(
      ([countBack,forward])=>[countBack,connectCount(forward,position,player)]
    ).map(
      ([countBack,countForward])=>countBack+countForward-1
    ).reduce(
      (highest,item)=>(item>highest)?item:highest,0
    );
  }
  const directions = [[0,-1],[-1,-1],[-1,0],[-1,1]].map(([x,y])=>[[x,y],[x*-1,y*-1]]);
  return countConnectedAllDirections(directions,position,player)>=4;
};
//Run some tests:
const rotate = grid =>//just to make the grid look normal in console.log
  grid[0].map((i,y)=>grid.map((i,x)=>[y,x]))
  .map((row)=>row.map(([y,x])=>grid[x][y]));
const format = grid => rotate(grid).map(row=>row.join(" ")).join("\n");
const test = (message,pass) =>
  (pass)
    ? console.log(`Passed: ${message}`)
    : console.error(`Failed: ${message}`)
//function to mutate grid setting items for testing
const setItem = (x,y,value) => grid[x][y]=value;
//7 by 6 grid containing -
const createGrid = () => Array.from(new Array(7),()=>Array.from(new Array(6),()=>"-"));
var grid = createGrid();
test("Should return false when position is empty",isWin(grid,[0,5])===false);
const posReducer = (all,pos)=>all&&isWin(grid,pos);
[[0,5],[0,4],[0,3]].forEach(([x,y])=>setItem(x,y,"X"));
console.log(format(grid));
test(
  "Should return false when position is not empty but not connect 4",
  [[0,5],[0,4],[0,3]].reduce((all,pos)=>all||isWin(grid,pos),false)===false 
);
[[0,5],[0,4],[0,3],[0,2]].forEach(([x,y])=>setItem(x,y,"X"));
console.log(format(grid));
test(
  "Should return true when position is not empty and connect 4 vertical",
  [[0,5],[0,4],[0,3],[0,2]].reduce(posReducer,true)
);
grid = createGrid();//reset grid
[[1,5],[2,5],[3,5],[4,5]].forEach(([x,y])=>setItem(x,y,"X"));
console.log(format(grid));
test(
  "Should return true when position is not empty and connect 4 horizontal",
  [[1,5],[2,5],[3,5],[4,5]].reduce(posReducer,true)
);
grid = createGrid();//reset grid
[[1,5],[2,4],[3,3],[4,2]].forEach(([x,y])=>setItem(x,y,"X"));
console.log(format(grid));
test(
  "Should return true when position is not empty and connect 4 diagonal bottom left to top right",
  [[1,5],[2,4],[3,3],[4,2]].reduce(posReducer,true)
);
grid = createGrid();//reset grid
[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5]].forEach(([x,y])=>setItem(x,y,"X"));
console.log(format(grid));
test(
  "Should return true when position is not empty and connect 4 diagonal top left to bottom right",
  [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5]].reduce(posReducer,true)
);
```

The following is the complete game:

```js
//view part
const [init,paint] = (()=>{
  const getStyle = gridValue => 
    (gridValue==="-")
      ? ""
      : `style="background-color:${(gridValue==="RED")?"red":"green"}"`;
  const createTD = ([x,y,gridValue]) => 
    `<td ${getStyle(gridValue)} data-role="turn" data-position="${x},${y}"></td>`;
  const createTR = gridRow => 
    `<tr>${gridRow.reduce((result,value)=>result+createTD(value),"")}</tr>`;
  const createTable = grid =>
      `<table>${
        grid.reduce((all,row)=>all+createTR(row),"")
      }</table>`
  ;
  const createMessage = message => `<div><h1>${message}</h1></div>`;
  const createResetButton = () => `<button data-role="reset">Reset</button>`;
  const createUndoRedo = () => `
    <div>
    <button data-role="undo_redo" data-direction="-1">Undo</button>
    <button data-role="undo_redo" data-direction="1">Redo</button>
    </div>
  `;
  const paint = state =>
      state.container.innerHTML = 
        createTable(state.grid) +
        createMessage(state.message) +
        createResetButton(state) +
        createUndoRedo();
  const init = state => state.container.addEventListener(
    "click",
    e=>{
      const role = e.target.getAttribute("data-role");
      if(role==="turn"){
        const xy = e.target.getAttribute("data-position");
        handleEvent(role,xy.split(",").map(Number));
      }
      if(role==="reset"){
        handleEvent(role,{});
      }
      if(role==="undo_redo"){
        const direction = e.target.getAttribute("data-direction");
        handleEvent(role,Number(direction));
      }
    }
  );
  return [init,paint];
})();


const handleEvent = (()=>{
  const createState = ([x,y])=>({
    grid:Array.from(new Array(x),()=>Array.from(new Array(y),()=>"-")),
    container:document.querySelector("#content"),
    currentPlayer:"RED",
    winner:false,
    message:`It's RED's turn`
  });
  var state = createState([7,6]);

  const isWin = (grid,position) => {
    const [x,y] = position;
    const player = grid[x][y];
    if(player==="-"){//current location in grid is empty, return false
      return false;
    }
    const countConnectedAllDirections = (directions,position,player) => {
      const connectCount = (direction,position,player,count=1)=>{
        const [x,y]=[position[0]+count*direction[0],position[1]+count*direction[1]];
        if((grid[x] && grid[x][y])!==player){
          return count;
        }
        return connectCount(direction,position,player,count+1);
      };
      return directions.map(
        ([back,forward])=>[connectCount(back,position,player),forward]
      ).map(
        ([countBack,forward])=>[countBack,connectCount(forward,position,player)]
      ).map(
        ([countBack,countForward])=>countBack+countForward-1
      ).reduce(
        (highest,item)=>(item>highest)?item:highest,0
      );
    }
    const directions = [[0,-1],[-1,-1],[-1,0],[-1,1]].map(([x,y])=>[[x,y],[x*-1,y*-1]]);
    return countConnectedAllDirections(directions,position,player)>=4;
  };
  const getAvailableIndex = (grid,x)=>{
    const getIndex = (arr,y) => {
      if(arr[y]==="-"){
        return y;
      }
      if(y<0){
        return false;
      }
      return getIndex(arr,y-1);
    }
    return getIndex(grid[x],grid[x].length-1);
  }
  const play = (player,grid,[posX,posY])=>{
    return grid.map((arr,x)=>arr.map(
      (val,y)=>(x===posX && y===posY) ? player : val
    ));
  }
  const rotateGrid = grid =>
    grid[0].map((i,y)=>grid.map((i,x)=>[y,x]))
    .map((row)=>row.map(([y,x])=>[x,y,grid[x][y]]));
  const paintRotate = state => paint({...state,grid:rotateGrid(state.grid)});
  const canMove = grid => grid.reduce(
    (result,ignore,index)=>result||(getAvailableIndex(grid,index)!==false),false
  )
  const handleEvent = ((states,statesIndex) => (eventType,data) =>{
    const newState={...states[statesIndex]};
    if(eventType==="turn"){
      if(newState.winner){
        return;
      }
      if(!canMove(newState.grid)){
        newState.message=`It's a draw, press reset to play again.`;
        paintRotate(newState);
        return;
      }
      const availableY = getAvailableIndex(newState.grid,data[0]);
      if(availableY===false){
        newState.message=`Cannot play this move, still ${newState.currentPlayer}'s turn.`
        if(states[statesIndex].message!==newState.message){
          statesIndex=states.length;
          states.push(newState);
          paintRotate(newState);
        }
        return;
      }
      statesIndex=states.length;
      const newGrid = play(newState.currentPlayer,newState.grid,[data[0],availableY]);
      newState.grid=newGrid;
      newState.winner=isWin(newState.grid,[data[0],availableY]);
      if(newState.winner){
        newState.message=`Winner is:${newState.currentPlayer}`;
        states.push(newState)
        paintRotate(newState);
        return;      
      }
      if(!canMove(newState.grid)){
        newState.message=`It's a draw, press reset to play again.`;
        states.push(newState);
        paintRotate(newState);
        return;
      }
      newState.currentPlayer=(newState.currentPlayer==="RED")?"GREEN":"RED";
      newState.message=`It's ${newState.currentPlayer}'s turn`;
      states.push(newState);
      paintRotate(newState);
    }
    if(eventType==="reset"){
      state = createState([newState.grid.length,newState.grid[0].length]);
      statesIndex=states.length;
      states.push(state);
      paintRotate(state);
    }
    if(eventType==="undo_redo"){
      const newIndex = statesIndex+data;
      if(newIndex<0){
        paintRotate({...states[statesIndex],message:"Cannot undo. "+states[statesIndex].message});
        return;
      }
      if(newIndex>=states.length){
        paintRotate({...states[statesIndex],message:"Cannot redo. "+states[statesIndex].message});
        return;
      }
      statesIndex=newIndex;
      paintRotate(states[statesIndex]);
    }
  })([state],0);
  init(state);
  paintRotate(state);
  return handleEvent;
})();
```

```css
td {
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  border:1px solid gray;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```